# sql attribute name

Tags: sql, oracle, attributes

I have a table with five columns and there is an attribute with the name `NoOfCreditCards`. This attribute's data type is varchar with length 2. When the table is shown in the SQL command line the name of the `NoOfCreditCards` column appears only as `No`, the rest part of the name does not appear. I have tried to use "set lin" with different sizes, but it did not work. How can i resolve this issue?

Comment: Which SQL engine are you using, and which client are you using to perform the query?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch6.htm#sthref1131

Answer (score 0):

You have to name the columns in your select statement.
Something like this:

```
SELECT NoOfCreditCards "NoOfCreditCards"
FROM TABLE
WHERE ...;
```